# How do I provide a global macro in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro I want to have automatically available to all Excel worksheets. So I have placed the file [AutoTagExcelMacro.xla](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ws2sqzve80tlm07/AutoTagExcelMacro.xla?dl=0) in the folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\XLSTART. And that seems to do the trick.

I've been told by Microsoft support that I then, after installing the file there, need to call [RunAutoMacros](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.runautomacros) on the installed file. Do I? And what does it do in this case? There is no Open or Activate macro in the macro.

Is this a way of registering it with Excel as something to always run? As I said, installing the file without running RunAutoMacros does make the macro available in all worksheets on our test systems. But all of our test systems have called RunAutoMacros in the past, so that past call may make a difference.

After copying the file to XLSTART, when I create a new workbook the macro is there in it. I did nothing but create a new workbook to get this:

[image]

Comment: Putting it on XLStart you only are sure that the file is open when Excel starts. This does not mean that you can just call a public function like in the working workbook code. There are to ways of accessing the macro from that specific Workbook, respectively: Using of `Application.Run` (which I mostly use), or adding a reference to that specific workbook VBProject. But, of course, changing the name from its default  `VBProject` in something specific. Only in such a case you can call the Function/Sub directly. But this involves creating of such references to all workbooks  that may need that.

Comment: Have you read about the PERSONAL.xlsb hidden workbook? I used to use this so functions are available on all worksheets. You can add buttons to the top of Excel so you can call these functions at any time on any open book https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/copy-your-macros-to-a-personal-macro-workbook-aa439b90-f836-4381-97f0-6e4c3f5ee566

Comment: @FaneDuru I think what you said is incorrect. Because the macro does show up in any new worksheet.

Comment: @David Thielen: What do you mean  by "macro does show up in any new worksheet"?

Comment: @FaneDuru Look at the screenshot above. I created a new workbook and then pressed Alt-F11. And that global macro is there and available. I didn't add it.

Comment: @David Thielen: Of course it is! Any add-in is loaded by Excel when it starts. Exactly the same is happens with any Excel file located in XLStart folder. This is what ai said.  "Putting it on XLStart you only are sure that the file is open when Excel starts". In my comment I was referring to the way of running the add-in procedures from the open workbooks... When you were referring to a Global Macro I supposed that you need to run it from the open workbooks. Wasn't that the meaning of your question?

Comment: @David Thielen: I've read again your question. I initially did not care about the way your add-in is loaded. I focused only on the way of calling its procedures. Now, placing the add-in in XLStart folder in not the most usual/normal way. Add-ins can be automatically installed (having some code on the Workbook_Open event) or manually like rva explains in his answer. Installing it in Excel, this operation will make Excel opening it. And like in your case, placing any kind of Excel file (xls, xlsx, xlsm, xla, xlam etc.) in XLStart folder, it will be open by Excel. Only open. So was Excel built...

Comment: @FaneDuru Yes - the requirement is they can use it in any worksheet and if they do, it runs. We install it in XLSTART as one of the steps of our installer.

Comment: @FaneDuru If you put the file AutoTagExcelMacro.xlam above in your C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\XLSTART folder and then put "=autotag('wr:out select="blah blah blah" nickname="dave"/>') - when the cell you put that in is not selected, does it just display dave? If so, then merely putting the xlam file in XLSTART makes the macro available in any workbook.

Comment: @David Thielen: Well, posting in this area (VBA tag), I imagined that the question refers to programmaticaly acces macros from all workbooks. If this was the meaning of your question, the answer would not be a strait one. The macros are more accessible then available. I mean, you can (in code) use a macro from ANY VBProject **in the ways I tried to explain in my first comment**.  Using of XLSTART, it will only open it. They would be available only from a special workbook type (Personal.xlsb). If your question refers to **manually using them through Developer Tab -> Macros, the answer is YES**.

Answer (score 0):

File > Options > Addins > Go >

then tick the box for the addin and click ok

Comment: I want to install it so that it is there automatically for all worksheets.

Comment: I downloaded your .xla and added it to excel as described above. I did forget to mention after go you will need to browse for it to add it. After I did that in every new workbook I open in every sheet I open both functions autotag and parseNode are available. I'm not sure what the issue is. By adding it this way you don't need the code in each sheet as it is globally available.

Comment: That's what I found too. But Microsoft paid support said we need to call RunAutoMacros and so I'm looking for confirmation that they're wrong. Or someone who explains the use case(s) where this is needed.

Comment: RunAutoMacros is what you use when you want code to be run everytime at say the open or close of the workbook. It's hard to say if they were wrong or not they may not have understood what you were asking to do. I think this will explain it better. https://analysistabs.com/vba-code/workbook/m/runautomacros/